# Why does my funnel look like that?

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics, goal-tracking

I've set up a goal with a funnel on Google Universal Analytics. The funnel starts at one domain and the second step is in another domain. I'm using linker to pass the client id to the new domain.

The weird thing is that it looks in the report like there are many entrances directly to the second step, which doesn't make sense. The only way to get to that step is to click a link in the first step. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: how certain are you that you can't go directly to the 2nd step's URL? What happens if you go directly there? Does a server redirect happen before GA Code is triggered? Also, are you certain the value you are using to qualify that goal step isn't also matching another URL?

Comment: It is technically almost impossible to get to the second stage manually. It's very unlikely that this is what so many users do. Users can't simply get there by typing in the URL of the second page. If the user is already logged in, then there is a server redirect instead of the second stage, directly to the last (or next to last) step in the funnel. But then I'd still expect to see those users starting in the first step. I'm certain the regexp are valid and unique per step.

Comment: OK, I think I've got a possible explanation. If the users are logged in then the server redirects to the last step, and the GA client id never gets read. So all of the users get to the last step with a different client id and the report backfills them all the way to the second step. It doesn't backfill to the first step since it has a different client id for all the sessions in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

What happens is that users who are not logged in yet get redirected to the sign in page and the GA code doesn't get executed until after they are redirected back after they login. So the login page gets a new client id.

The solution I came up with was to tweak with the redirection logic (devise) and to pass the _ga parameter to the login screen.